# use ceemd of pyeemd in python2.7.12

Tags: python, time-series

I used ceemd of pyeemd(libeemd),but the residual is Nan after ceemd when the source data is with length 16.

```
This is source data0 
[ 532.038  532.467  532.897  532.579  531.834  531.089  530.344  530.243
  529.637  529.871  530.586  531.302  531.528  531.674  531.562  531.562]

This is the imfs for souce data0 
[[  4.99536300e-02   5.07521024e-01   1.15778456e+00   1.12993996e+00
    7.67565359e-01   4.12133844e-01  -1.81761588e-02   1.82634342e-02
   -5.76022792e-01  -5.16983337e-01  -8.86904761e-02   2.36815870e-01
    1.38870440e-01   7.08367478e-02  -1.27149210e-01  -1.13787989e-01]
 [ -4.58838235e-04   1.18438903e-01   1.53245692e-01   1.34404459e-01
    7.60518794e-02   1.67176195e-02  -3.79650223e-02  -5.60086247e-02
   -7.75462828e-02  -7.00926985e-02  -2.94792254e-02   3.22931827e-02
    6.15527167e-02   5.16516550e-02   4.25997864e-03  -5.38057521e-02]
 [ -1.13008493e-01   1.05889951e-01   1.65761000e-01   1.63480749e-01
    6.48455348e-02  -9.18077666e-02  -2.36833140e-01  -2.97692545e-01
   -2.79863120e-01  -1.55546830e-01  -1.07397933e-02   1.61763712e-01
    2.56023595e-01   2.38445996e-01   9.00409154e-02  -1.86476311e-01]
 [             nan              nan              nan              nan
               nan              nan              nan              nan
               nan              nan              nan              nan
               nan              nan              nan              nan]]
Plotting IMF #1
Plotting IMF #2
Plotting IMF #3
Plotting Residual

This is source data1 
[ 530.524  530.452  530.417  530.176  530.567  530.731  530.878  531.32
  531.942  532.039  531.816  531.593  531.126  531.353  531.257  531.248]

This is the imfs for source data1 
[[-0.06378673 -0.07530695 -0.04069713 -0.30207195 -0.02267617 -0.07398937
  -0.21837115 -0.12946676  0.21435049  0.18605721  0.04908956  0.00394656
  -0.26659788  0.08695065  0.04803377  0.02217659]
 [ 0.03048818  0.01693255 -0.02122604 -0.06449743 -0.08466269 -0.0725593
  -0.04595078  0.01500129  0.07128166  0.07859381  0.03046378 -0.04452977
  -0.0963699  -0.09101547 -0.05157518 -0.003445  ]
 [ 0.20185892 -0.00429606 -0.19287011 -0.27632151 -0.27612168 -0.19247013
  -0.03727295  0.15981007  0.30781758  0.37327476  0.29858615  0.17610284
   0.03574206 -0.06765531 -0.1129184  -0.07166027]
 [        nan         nan         nan         nan         nan         nan
          nan         nan         nan         nan         nan         nan
          nan         nan         nan         nan]]
Plotting IMF #1
Plotting IMF #2
Plotting IMF #3
Plotting Residual
```

but when source data is with length 15, the residual have values. It's so 
strange.

```
    This is source data3 
   [ 530.586  531.302  531.528  531.674  531.562  531.562  531.562  531.374
      531.327  531.291  531.255  531.22   530.633  529.731  529.585]
    This is the imfs for souse data3 
    [[ -2.57647365e-01   7.06629505e-02   8.39936544e-02   1.03626646e-01
       -3.77084389e-02  -6.94455383e-03   6.69430411e-02  -6.02568977e-02
       -3.56135227e-02  -8.89493294e-03   9.26811241e-02   2.66926679e-01
        1.55859560e-02  -4.61294251e-01  -1.08736263e-01]
     [ -1.22334516e-01  -9.62117206e-03   2.97368189e-02   2.55569834e-02
        1.07972419e-02   7.11036508e-03  -2.77185842e-03  -1.04815159e-02
       -9.74577355e-03   6.71936342e-03   2.79127814e-02   2.45918227e-02
       -4.30061520e-03  -4.39506421e-02  -9.01203233e-02]
     [  5.30965982e+02   5.31240958e+02   5.31414270e+02   5.31544816e+02
        5.31588911e+02   5.31561834e+02   5.31497829e+02   5.31444738e+02
        5.31372359e+02   5.31293176e+02   5.31134406e+02   5.30928481e+02
        5.30621715e+02   5.30236245e+02   5.29783857e+02]]
    Plotting IMF #1
    Plotting IMF #2
    Plotting Residual
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in `libeemd` which is now fixed: https://bitbucket.org/luukko/pyeemd/issues/3/residual-is-nan-when-the-source-data-is